# Kendo hierarchy grid -- get count of child rows on selecting master row

Tags: kendo-grid

I think this is probably pretty simple, but I need pointing in the right direction.

I've got a master/child grid and I'd simply like to be able to get a count of child rows when selecting (or various other actions, e.g. save or edit ) the master row.

Thanks

Comment: There's no code because it's a general question. The code would be as per Kendo's basic hierarchy [grid demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/hierarchy.html). I'd like to know how you'd go about getting a count of child records within, say, the `change` event of the master grid.

Comment: I guess jQuery is allowed!?

Comment: Sure. It's used pretty extensively already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a fiddle and played around a bit. It's not always working, e.g. when you haven't got the details grid yet or when opening a detail row for the first time, but it should give you an idea on how get the cound of a hierarchical grid.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9BGpr/

Open console to get output.

Main code is here:

```
    selectable: 'row',
    change: function (e) {
        var kendoGrid = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("e", e)
            var $selectedRow = kendoGrid.select();
            if ($selectedRow.length != 1) {
                console.log("Please select a single row!");
                return false;
            }
            if ($selectedRow.hasClass('k-master-row')) {
                var $detailRow = $selectedRow.next().filter('.k-detail-row');

                if ($detailRow.length === 0) {
                    console.log("Could not find detail row!");
                    return false;
                }

                var $detailGrid = $detailRow.find('.k-grid');

                if ($detailGrid.length === 0) {
                    console.log("Could not find grid in detail row!");
                    return false;
                }

                var kendoGridDetails = $detailGrid.getKendoGrid();

                console.log("Total of records in detail grid: " + kendoGridDetails.dataSource.total());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes. That looks like it will work for what I need (I think). Thanks.